# How to snap a window to the middle of the screen using keyboard shortcuts in Cinnamon?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

I installed Linux Mint 19 "Tara" with Cinnamon 3.8.6.
I'm able to use the "windows" aka "super" key plus left or right arrow to snap opened windows to the left or right of the screen.  With a large monitor (3440x1440), I'm often dragging windows to the middle, so it would be nice if there was a keyboard shortcut for this.  Using a keyboard shortcut would be preferred, but if there was another way using the mouse, that would be fine too.
 I tried going through the system settings (particularly under "Windows") and couldn't find any options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking to center a window on my widescreen monitor (IE to center a browser window to read an article). Ideally I could specify different layouts and quickly position windows in them, or even jump between layouts.

Check out the gTile Spice extension (install via Extensions).
https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/21

It's not exactly what I wanted, but can be used to do it. I defined a 4x1 grid, select the browser, and use the hotkeys to position it in the center 2 cells. The other tiling options to automatically position multiple windows didn't really work for me though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wmctrl.

`wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 1,900,450,1500,1500`, the five options are: “gravity,X,Y,width,height”.

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/wmctrl/